# PHP setcookie() - Removing cookies which are from parent path

Tags: php, cookies

Is it be possible to remove cookies from `sub_dir` which are already set in `parent_dir`? For example:

```
Set Cookies Path = "localhost/dir"
Removing From Path = "localhost/dir/dir"
```

I tried like this:

```
 setcookie("name", '', time() - 100, "dir/", "localhost/");
```

, however it does't work.

How can it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Just learn the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

The **path** on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.

Create a cookie for localhost/dir example:

```
setcookie("cookie-name", 'value', time() + 3600, "/dir/");
```

Remove this cookie:

```
setcookie("cookie-name", NULL, -1, "/dir/");
```

Comment: is this way to remove cookies from anywhere in the website?

Comment: This cookie will be visible only for /dir/ and all sub-directories as /dir/dir/ etc.

Comment: That's not what was asked. The question was "can an HTTP response for resource example.com/foo/bar delete a cookie that is set to example.com/foo" Will the browser delete it or ignore it because the resource is not allowed to access it's parent?